# Is is possible to have a protocol target dependent in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, mac-catalyst

I am trying to use selective compilation to have only one version of my AppDelegate, but having one for set of protocols (specifically NSTouchBarDelegate) in the Mac version (using MacCatalyst).  Seems when the target is not for the Mac, Xcode can't find the protocol.

I've tried to use:

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
    #if targetEnvinronment(macCatalyst)
    , NSTouchBarDelegate
    #endif
    {
```

but the compiler comes back with:

[image]

other then a separate Responder for the TouchBar, any ideas?

Comment: An extension to the class?

Comment: Or just put the protocols in a different order, to prevent the loose leading comma.

Comment: The latter does not work.   Thanks for the former.

Answer (score 1):

For the uninitiated:

```
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    extension AppDelegate: NSTouchBarDelegate {}
    #endif
```

Great solution.